# How do I test my LMS against SCORM 2004 3rd Edition?

Tags: scorm

I have developed an LMS based on ASP.NET 3.5 and C# after working for 4 years. Now I don't know how can I test it against SCORM 2004 3rd Edition to see if it is conformant or not. I read the SCORM 2004 3rd Edition Conformance Requirements book and also SCORM 2004 3rd Edition Conformance Test Suite readme file but couldn't understand how do I test my LMS.

Answer (score 1):

ADL provides a free conformance test suite that you can test your LMS against. You can download it from their site at http://www.adlnet.gov/capabilities/scorm/scorm-2004-3rd#tab-resources.

Unless you made an intentional effort to make it SCORM conformant, it is not going to pass the tests. For the basics on how to get started with SCORM read SCORM Explained at http://scorm.com/scorm-explained/.

Comment: Mike Rustici, I have downloaded the Conformance Test Suite and LMS Test Content Packages, too. What should I do now?